# On SourceForge, is there a way to receive a notification when a project releases a new version?

Tags: sourceforge

There was a time when it was easy to subscribe to a project and receive mail when a new release came out. Then the new subscriptions was suspended because of a site upgrade and I was still receiving the mails from previously subscribed projects but I never found the option to subscribe to new projects, even when the upgrade was finished.

Was the option restored? Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to a File Release RSS.

Taken from :

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Links%20to%20available%20site-wide%20RSS%20feeds

> ```
> Project RSS Feed: Project File Releases
> Description: A feed of the most recent file releases made by a
> project, including details of the > files included in the release. 
>
> Related site URL (i.e. source of content): File Release page for
> project URL to feed: Project-specific URL 
> Feed options: &rss_limit=LIMIT 
> - Limit (or increase the limit of) the number items shown in the feed
> (default 10, max 100) where LIMIT is a positive integer
>
> Feed usage: Rather than monitoring a file release package and receiving
> updates via email, you may instead use this RSS feed to keep apprised
> of when file releases are made by a project. 
>
> Content notes: This feed includes basic file release information
> (title); as well as the username of the developer who handled the file
> release, a listing of files within the > release, and links to downloadable
> files and release notes (description). Additional information about the File
> Release System may be found in our, "Guide to the File Release System".
> ```

Comment: Meh, I want to keep receiving the mails. Do I still have this option?

Comment: Not as far as I know, so that's why I have been registering to the RSS feeds of certain projects instead.